# If record in table A does not exist in table B do something, how would I go about doing this?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table A with a field called emails I need to check table B that also has a field called emails. If an email in table A does not show in table B I need to do something.

Here is the sql part I have so far

```
$check=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_appointment WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM default_consultation)");
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track and if I am I am not sure how to implement the php portion. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at MySQL [EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

```
SELECT *
FROM default_appointment a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM default_consultation c
  WHERE c.email = a.email
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$check=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_appointment WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT      email FROM default_consultation)");


  $row_count = $this->db->num_rows($check);

  if($row_count > 1)
  {
    // do your stuff
  }
```

hope it works